# Nexenta storage metro cluster - what are components involved?

Tags: storage, nexenta, illumos

As Nexenta is built on Illumos, a successor of OpenSolaris, I was wondering what components are involved in their storage metro clustering?

Can anybody enlight me as to what components are doing this site-to-site mirroring?

If these components are open source, is it possible to build your own site-to-site storage cluster?

Answer (score 1):

I'd assume that the replication/cluster modules are unique to NexentaStor. The feature is available to a licensed version of NexentaStor, though, so you don't necessarily have to build your own.